# Reading a request Ip address in c#

Tags: c#

I have a login page where the user can login to my website when the user click on the submit button in the login page I want to read it's Ip address how ca i do this is c# I tried this

```
   Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but the result was `::1` is it because I am logging in from the local machine or the statement that I used above is wrong?

Comment: Nuke this question then.

Answer (score 2):

That's basically the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1` so is technically correct. If you don't use or need IPv6 disable it in the network adapter settings.

Answer (score 2):

`::1` is the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address, your code is correct.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1932843/413180) for details.